# QLPreviewController works with URLs provided by UIDocumentBrowserViewController, but not with URLs generated manually

Tags: uikit, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller, ios12, uidocumentbrowservc

I'm using UIDocumentBrowserViewController combined with QLPreviewController to preview documents selected by users in UIDocumentBrowserViewController, which works perfectly fine. The `pickedDocumentURL` variable used by `QLPreviewController` is populated as follows:

---

```
func documentBrowser(_ controller: UIDocumentBrowserViewController, didPickDocumentURLs documentURLs: [URL]) {
    // (...)

    pickedDocumentURL = documentURLs.first as NSURL?

    // Present QLPreviewController instance ...
}
```

---

However, when I populate the `pickedDocumentURL` variable using:

```
pickedDocumentURL = NSURL(string: documentURLs.first!.absoluteString)
```

or:

```
pickedDocumentURL = URL(string: documentURLs.first!.absoluteString) as NSURL?
```

... then the `QLPreviewController` does not work (it is presented, but the preview is empty) and I get the following error on the console:

---

> [default] QLUbiquitousItemFetcher:  could not create sandbox wrapper. Error: Error
>   Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "couldn't issue sandbox extension
>   com.apple.quicklook.readonly for
>   '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/07524B34-D877-449F-A5C3-89A0431560E5/File
>   Provider
>   Storage/22207162/1qrbGgy6-u0f69mPqOjjpzlYiUYPR8OG_/Sample.pdf':
>   Operation not permitted" UserInfo={NSDescription=couldn't issue
>   sandbox extension com.apple.quicklook.readonly for
>   '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/07524B34-D877-449F-A5C3-89A0431560E5/File
>   Provider
>   Storage/22207162/1qrbGgy6-u0f69mPqOjjpzlYiUYPR8OG_/Sample.pdf':
>   Operation not permitted} #PreviewItem

Moreover, the URL absolute strings in each of those cases are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

you are using .absoluteString, use .path instead, I had same issue and this solved it:

```
pickedDocumentURL = NSURL(string: documentURLs.first!.path)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the code that works for me:

```
func getPreviewItem(withName name: String ) -> NSURL
{
    //let file = name.components(separatedBy: ".")
    let pdfFile = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(name)
    let url = pdfFile as NSURL (this line was the key)
    return url
}
```